# Laravel 5.5 - Check checkbox if role has permission

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have the following code that works with the Form Collective package, however this isn't working right now as the package hasn't been updated for 5.5. I am also using Spatie's Laravel Permission package

The code I have is

```
@foreach ($permissions as $permission)

    {{Form::checkbox('permissions[]',  $permission->id, $role->permissions ) }}
    {{Form::label($permission->name, ucfirst($permission->name)) }}<br>

@endforeach
```

Which I believe is just looping through the `permissions` and if the `permission` belongs to the current `role` check the box.

How can I achieve this without using the package?

I have currently tried

```
@foreach ($permissions as $permission)

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            {{ ucfirst($permission->name) }}
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $permission->id }}">
        <br>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

But I'm not sure how to attach the checked attribute based on whether the role has a permission in the list.

Comment: This is not actually depending on Laravel itself, but it's rather an HTML question. Anyway i posted the answer below

Comment: No it is dependant on Laravel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the `checked` attribute to the checkbox HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $permission->id }}" checked>
```

if you need to set it upon a condition use the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $permission->id }}" @if(/* some condition */) checked @endif>
```

**EDIT**

Since i didn't understand the question before i'll add some details.

Assuming that your `Role` model has a collection of attached permissions and it is stored in the attribute `$role->permissions` you could do

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $permission->id }}" @if($role->permissions->contains($permission)) checked @endif>
```

That way you can check if your role has the permission with id `$permission->id`.

Comment: This doesn't help, I know I can add a check attribute, but I need to understand how to query the role to see if the permission exists to check the box

Comment: Oh i see, it's not really clear from the question itself, i will edit my answer

Comment: It should address your problem now

Comment: Ah yeah that works, thanks! Just going to see what it is I was missing

Comment: Happy to help. I've just looked at Spatie Laravel Permissions and this syntax should work out of the box

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@foreach ($permissions as $permission)

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            {{ ucfirst($permission->name) }}
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $permission->id }} {{($role->permissions == $permission->id) ? 'checked' : ''}}">
        <br>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: All of my check boxes are empty, but I have 3 roles that have varied permissions between them so should expect to see a couple checked at least

Comment: How are you saving the permissions in your DB?

Comment: Yeah, thats because `$role->permissions` is a collection and `$permission->id` is an integer. So basically you're comparing the whole collection to an id, and that will always return `false`.

Comment: I'm using the Spatie Laravel Permissions - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: Could you post the result of dd($role->permissions); ?

Comment: change `$role->permissions == $permission->id` to `$role->permissions->contains('id', $permission->id)`

Comment: @Wreigh it is not required to specify the parameter in `contains` as long as the collection is an Eloquent collection, `contains` will check for every model in the collection if `$model->is($other)` where `is` is equivalent to `$model->getKey() === $other->getKey()`